# (Background image) logo getting cut-off in full screen on Desktop depending on window dimensions

Tags: html, image, css

[Screenshots of the issue](https://imgur.com/a/MFi4O) <- When in a portrait phone sized window it does okay, when fullscreened on desktop the logo gets clipped.

I have an image that I'm trying to use as a background image. The image was given to me with a bunch of UI elements and a company logo on it, and I erased all the UI elements with photoshop but left the company logo on the image.

I found [this CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) which gave me an easy way to keep the image responsive when I resized the window (wanted to make sure it looked okay on mobile too) but then I noticed **The company logo at the top was getting cut off**. For reference, the logo is at the near top of the image and is centered.

I used this code from the CSS tricks article:

```
html { 
    background: url("img/image.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

and this is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainpageStyles.css">

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a better way to make sure the image stays centered within the window and doesn't get cut-off?

I've also noticed that if the window is too wide and too short the logo can disappear entirely. Should I have the logo scrubbed in Photoshop and display it as a separate image or can I fix this with CSS?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot ?

Comment: @acoder yeah sorry about that, added to the post and I will also place it here https://imgur.com/a/MFi4O

Comment: Can you add the html code. You can add `margin` or `padding` for fix this in desktop version. @Ryan

Comment: @acoder okay added the html. Trying to mess with the margins/padding. Although when I try changing them nothing is happening.

Comment: oh. the logo is also in the bg image.

Comment: @acoder right. I wasn't sure if I should've separated the logo out of the background image and then displayed it as a separate image on top of the background or something.. or if it would work as part of the image. Should I scrub the logo and display them separately?

Comment: yeah . you should use separately .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160816/discussion-between-acoder-and-ryan).

Comment: You can try `background: url("img/image.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed`, but using  the logo separately would be a better option.